# Show more and show less by Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a button named `Read More`

Which will display some more content when clicked. When it displays the content, the button text should be changed to be `Read less`.

```js
$(".read-more a").on("click", function() {
  var $link = $(this);
  var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");
  var linkText = $link.text();

  $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");

  $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));

  return false;
});

function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
  var newText = '';

  if (currentText.toUpperCase() === "READ MORE") {
    newText = "Read More";
  } else {
    newText = "Read Less";
  }

  return newText;
}
```

```css
div.text-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.text-content{
  line-height: 1em;
}

.short-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2em;
}

.full-text{
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.read-more {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-content short-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Any advice and/or help would be really appreciated.

---

[(Here a jfiddle what I have tried)](https://jsfiddle.net/uzzimu/4cgbLne4/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your answer. Please try this.
https://jsfiddle.net/4cgbLne4/12/

```
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="text-content short-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </div>
    <div>
        <button href="#" class="read-more">Read More</button>
    </div>
</div>

$(".read-more").on("click", function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");
    var linkText = $link.text();

    $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");

    $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));

    return false;
});

function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
    var newText = '';
        alert(currentText)
    if (currentText.toUpperCase() === "READ MORE") {
        newText = "Read Less";
    } else {
        newText = "Read More";
    }

    return newText;
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer, you are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve it without Javascript,

```css
.text-container {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 3px double;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}
.text-container .read-more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .5em;
 }
input.read-more-toggle { display: none; }
.read-more span { display: block; color: red; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline; }
.read-more span:last-child { display: none; }
input:checked + .read-more span:last-child { display: block; }
input:checked + .read-more span:first-child { display: none; }
.text-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.read-more + .text-content {
  max-height: 3em;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
input:checked + .read-more + .text-content {
  max-height: 50em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <input type=checkbox id=more-text-toggle-1 class=read-more-toggle />
  <label class="read-more" for="more-text-toggle-1">
    <span>read more</span>
    <span>read less</span>
  </label>
  <div class="text-content short-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

HTML

```
<div class="text-container">
  <div class="text-content short-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="read-more">
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".read-more button").on("click", function() {

  var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");

  $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");

  if ($(this).text() == 'Read More')
    $(this).text('Read Less');
  else
    $(this).text('Read More');
  return false;
});
```

[Example Fiddle - UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/4cgbLne4/8/)

Comment: thank you so much but I need it with the button not with the text, so the Read More/ Read Less should be a button , how can I do that, do you know !

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in toggling *More* and *Less* text:

```js
$(".read-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");
    var linkText = $link.text();
    $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");
    $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));
});

function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
    var newText = '';

    if (currentText.toUpperCase() == "READ MORE") {
        newText = "Read Less";
    } else {
        newText = "Read More";
    }

    return newText;
}
```

```css
.short-text{color:#000000}
.full-text{color:#ff8800}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="text-content short-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </div>
    <div class="read-more">
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For `<button>` get text by `.text()` and set text by `.html('text')`

For `<input type="button">` get text by `.val()` and set text by `.val('text')`

Comment: thank you so much but I need it with the button not with the text, so the Read More/ Read Less should be a button , how can I do that, do you know !

Comment: Check last lines of answer again

Comment: I have tried it many times but still could not manage to do it, thanks why I put the question here, could you kindly help me to solve this issue !

Comment: Sorry I can not guess what is problem. I have wrote about mistake in toggling and Also how to convert link to a button.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to switch the "more" / "less" in your function:

```
function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
    var newText = '';

    if (currentText.toUpperCase().trim() === "READ MORE") {
        newText = "Read Less";
    } else {
        newText = "Read More";
    }
    return newText;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4cgbLne4/5/

Comment: thank you so much but I need it with the button not with the text, so the Read More/ Read Less should be a button , how can I do that, do you know !

Answer (score 0):

Just added one token into this and changed condition on click of a tag

```
var token = 1;
$(".read-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $content = $link.parent().prev("div.text-content");
    var linkText = $link.text();

    $content.toggleClass("short-text, full-text");

    $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));

        if(token == 1)
    {
        $(this).text("Read Less");
      token = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text("Read More");
        token = 1;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cgbLne4/9/)

Comment: Thank you but I need it with a button but as I said in the question when I tried it with the button nothing works https://jsfiddle.net/uzzimu/4cgbLne4/13/

Comment: You already got an answer, still I have just completed above example with as simple as possible code for your reference [Here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cgbLne4/14/). Have a happy coding.